# How to make function return SymbolName or alternate name string if a function parameter is given

Tags: function-construction, string-manipulation, symbols

**Abstract:** I have a function `objectName[...]` that works just fine for variables (symbols) set to numerical results or strings which returns their unevaluated `SymbolName` even when nested inside a function `makeGridRow[...]` for created rows.

But I need it to be conditional so that if I feed it an alternate string name `altname` to use through a function parameter I want it to return that string inside the row function so I created an alternate version of `makeGridRow2[...,altname_]` to do that but it doesn't work.

**About Original `makeGridRow`** This code works but it doesn't have an option for returning an alternate name (instead of SymbolName).

**About makeGridRow2** This is an attempt to return an alternate name `altname` instead of SymbolName but it doesn't work at all.

```
congruence = {rule = " \[Rule] "};
objectName = Function[Null, SymbolName[Unevaluated[#]], {HoldFirst}];
SetAttributes[{makeGridRow, makeGridRow2}, HoldFirst];
makeGridRow[symbol_, prepend_ : "", 
   append_ : ""] := {Row[{prepend, objectName[symbol], append, rule}, 
    " "], TraditionalForm[symbol]};
makeGridRow2[symbol_, prepend_ : "", append_ : "", altname_: "", 
  separator_ : rule] := Block[{name},
  name = If[StringLength[altname] > 0, altname, objectName[symbol], 
    objectName[symbol];
    {Row[{prepend, name, append, separator}, " "], 
     TraditionalForm[symbol]}
    ]
  ]

num = 123;
objectName[num]
makeGridRow[num, "prepend", "append"]
makeGridRow2[num, "prepend", "append"]
makeGridRow2[num, "prepend", "append", "alternate name"]

str = "a string";
objectName[str]
makeGridRow[str, "prepend", "append"]
makeGridRow2[str, "prepend", "append"]
makeGridRow2[str, "prepend", "append", "alternate name"]
```

Comment: Typo in `..., altname_ "", ...`?

Comment: As swish says, there ought to be a colon in there...

Comment: @J.M. and @swish

I fixed colon `altname=:""` but it still doesn't work. Please have another look at this.

Comment: Check your `[` `]` balance, it's not doing what you think it does.

Comment: @swish nice catch! it worked.